# XSLT: Parse comma separated text from an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I have a xml that looks like below

```
<xsl:template match="//xml">
    <xsl:for-each select="//z:row"> 
      <ul class ="cstm-quicklinks">
        <li>        
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">                             
                      <xsl:value-of select="@ows_urlwmenu" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Title0"/>
            </a>


        </li>
    </ul>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

It did not give me the value of @ows_urlwmenu. Because the o/p of that attribute returns the value as:
ows_urlwmenu="http://www.google.com, http://www.google.com"
The reason for two same Urls is because one is the description and the other is the actual link. I want the Url that is a clickable link, which opens a site. 
How would I do that? Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only two values (one comma), then [`substring-after()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after) will suffice (to select the second link):

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@ows_urlwmenu, ', ')"/>
```

If I misinterpreted your question, and it's the first of the two links that you want, then `substring-before()`.

I hope this helps,